# Powershell Citrix ShareFile API Upload

Tags: powershell, citrix, fileshare

My code as below:

$ShareFileHomeFolder = (Send-SfRequest $sfClient -Entity Items).Url

```
New-PSDrive -Name sfDrive -PSProvider ShareFile -Client $sfClient -Root "\" -RootUri $ShareFileHomeFolder 

Copy-SfItem -Path $File.FullName -Destination "sfDrive:\Test"

Remove-PSDrive sfdrive
```

***Current:***
It's copy the files unto **Personal Folders\Test**

***This is what I want to achieve:***
How can I copy the files unto **Shared With Me\Reports\Folder1**?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Regards,
Micheale

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I managed to solved it.

```
#$_.Id is the folder ID you want to upload; xyz is your organisation
            
$ShareFileHomeFolder = "https://xyz.sf-api.com/sf/v3/Items("+$_.Id+")"          
            
##Create a PowerShell provider for ShareFile at the location specified
            
New-PSDrive -Name sfDrive -PSProvider ShareFile -Client $sfClient -Root "\" -RootUri $ShareFileHomeFolder
            
Copy-SfItem -Path $File.FullName -Destination "sfDrive:"
            
Remove-PSDrive sfdrive
```

Thanks.

Regards,
Micheale